# Как указать путь к pipenv в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pip, python-3.6, pipenv

Я запустил `Pycharm`, всплыло окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По ошибке я указал путь к `vitualenv`, а не к `pipenv`, выплыло окно с предупреждением:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нажал на Cancel, думая, что можно будет изменить путь, но окно просто закрылось

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне теперь указать `PyCharm` путь к `pipenv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это PyCharm  то так Settings - Tools - Python Integrated Tools

Comment: Я указал ссылку на pipenv, однако, при попытке использовать эту команду, выплывает сообщение: Имя "pipenv" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути,
 после чего повторите попытку
Подскаите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать